# Java - Super Call Issues

Tags: java, class, constructor, super

I'm new here, so some of my formatting may be odd.

I'm having some trouble calling a super constructor. Every time I compile my runner class, I'm getting a few errors:

```
.class expected" or "; expected
```

What's going on here?

(Code)

[image]

(Compiler output)

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: It says I need 10 reputation to post a picture...

Comment: not picture your code

Comment: You should always type out your code, not post pictures

Comment: I've added links to the code, so I hope you guys can help!

Comment: Post your code, we are way to lazy to follow links.

Comment: the way you're invoking super constructor is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call your super-constructor like this:

```
super(y,m,d);
```

Of course, that begs the question where those three values are supposed to come from. Probably you want to add three parameters to your own constructor:

```
public DateDriver(int y, int m, int d){
   super(y,m,d);
}
```

**But:** Why would you want to extend `Date` in the first place?

Comment: So the project I'm working on requires that I create a driver class to extend to a file called Date. That's where all my methods and stuff are. In the Date class, I've got three variables assigned: int year, int month, and int day.

Comment: So you have some `Date.java` to build upon? Then you need to be careful to keep that apart from `java.util.Date` (which I think is being used here, as you import it).

Comment: But do double-check. Usually a "driver" creates and exercises instances of a class, but does not subclass it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare variables inside the parameter section of a call to `super()`;

Perhaps what you need is:

```
public DateDriver(int y, int m, int d) {
    super(y, m, d);
}
```

Then when you construct the DateDriver object in your `main()` method, you pass in values for `y`, `m` and `d`.

Answer (score 0):

`super(int x, int x, int d);` does not make sense. It looks like you're trying to declare them while you're passing them in? If there exists a constructor in date with three `int` parameters, then you have to overload that one... not the no-parameter constructor:

```
public DateDriver(int y, int m, int d) {
    super(y, m, d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right syntax is

```
DateDriver()
{
   super(x, y, z);
   /* other code */
}
```

Always keep first line for a constructor call. If you want to make constructor chaining or you want to call parent class constructor.

example :

```
//for constructor chaining
DateDriver()
{
   this(x, y, z);
}
// for super call
DateDriver()
{
   this(x, y, z);
}
```